# Why my Keras CNN model isn't learning

Tags: machine-learning, python, neural-network, cnn, image-classification

My project have to decide if a image is 'pdr' or 'nonPdr', and I have 391 images (22 of PDR class, and the 369 of nonPdr)..

In my first model i was trying this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57663233/my-keras-cnn-return-the-same-output-value-how-can-i-fix-improve-my-code
.. and my return was always the same...

Now I made some changes in my model file:

```py
TRAIN_DIR = 'train_data/'
#TEST_DIR = 'test_data/'

def ReadImages(Path):
    LabelList = list()
    ImageCV = list()

    # Get all subdirectories
    FolderList = os.listdir(Path)

    # Loop over each directory
    for File in FolderList:
        if(os.path.isdir(os.path.join(Path, File))):
            for Image in os.listdir(os.path.join(Path, File)):
                # Convert the path into a file
                ImageCV.append(cv2.imread(os.path.join(Path, File) + os.path.sep + Image))    
                # Add a label for each image and remove the file extension
                classes = ["nonPdr", "pdr"]
                LabelList.append(classes.index(os.path.splitext(File)[0]))
        else:
            ImageCV.append(cv2.imread(os.path.join(Path, File) + os.path.sep + Image))    
            # Add a label for each image and remove the file extension
            classes = ["nonPdr", "pdr"]
            LabelList.append(classes.index(os.path.splitext(File)[0]))

    return ImageCV, LabelList

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3,3), padding="same",activation="relu", input_shape=(605,700,3)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(128,  kernel_size=(4,4), padding="same",activation="relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(2, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(optimizer='RMSprop', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

data, labels = ReadImages(TRAIN_DIR)

data = np.array(data, dtype="float") / 255.0

le = LabelEncoder()
labels = le.fit_transform(labels)
labels = np_utils.to_categorical(labels, 2)

model.fit(data, labels, epochs=8, batch_size=20)

model.save('model.h5')
```

... but running this code give me a Loss = 8.0 and a acc = 0.50

What can I do? I appreciate any answer..

**UPDATE** I forgot that I reduce my train imgs to 20/20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you have an output size of 2 in your final layer, while you should rather have size 1 (because of your sigmoid output and binary cross entropy loss).

Also, don’t use the `to_categorical` transformation as you only have two classes so no need to one-hot encode.

Try to change this and see if training improves.

Comment: `ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_1 to have shape (1,) but got array with shape (2,)` I have two classes..

Comment: I’ve edited the answer, don’t use to_categorical

Comment: I had the same output.. please see my update, i reduce to 20 pdr and 20 nonpdr images in my train data..

Comment: @Gilberto yep, but still it should not change the issue. However this is very little data and a CNN would hardly work.

Comment: so what can i do?

Comment: @Gilberto if you cannot gather more data, it seems difficult to apply machine learning.

Comment: how much pdr imgs i have to have

Comment: Hard to say, at least 50-100 per class so that you can evaluate the model. Also, have a look at a pre-trained model or try a simple linear model of flattened pixels to begin.

Comment: With 71 imgs it can work?